# Haskell Diagrams Graphviz Gtk Display alignment and scaling

Tags: haskell, graphviz, haskell-diagrams

I want to display a graph layed out by `graphviz` (via `Data.GraphViz`) in a Gtk window. The code I have does not automatically center the graph or size the diagram. I have setup a github repo with an example (see `src/Main.hs` at https://github.com/avras/diagrams-gtk-graphviz-example. I get the following output.

[image]

If I try showing a circle of radius one, I get the following output (which is expected). The code for this example is at `src/Circle.hs` in the same github repository. `Main.hs` and `Circle.hs` differ only in the diagram which is rendered (afaict).

[image]

**How can I get the graph to be centered in the window with the right width automatically calculated?**

I had to play around with the argument to `mkWidth` to get this picture. Also without setting `lw 0.005` the result was the following. The line width seems to be very large.

[image]

**EDIT** Here is the result after the fix suggested by Joachim Breitner.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, but I assume that the circle is centered on the origin `(0,0)`, and the diagram is put in the unit square (between `(0,0)` and `(1,1)`).

I would guess that if you remove the line

```
GRC.translate (w/2) (h/2)
```

in `Main.hs` it will work.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I have pushed the change to the github repo.